# For every thousand the number gets

Tags: javascript

**Infinite loop for every 1000**

Lets say i have a number 1000, and when it gets to 2000 or 3000, etc. I want to do a function. I want it to go to the infinite.

Tried almost everything...

Comment: Can you share the things that you have done? no one can help you without this

Comment: I ment it like i have a clicker game. So you when you click you get 1 score. If you have 1000 score, 2000, 3000, etc. it will do something. So i just want to follow my number of score and do a function.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood well, you can do

```
while(true){
  if(number%1000){
   //call function here
  }
  //increase the number here, for example:
  number++;
}
```

Comment: Now i have a score of 12042. I want it that when it gets to 13000 it does something... like play a sound or something.

Comment: So, where I putted `//call function here` you can call a function that will do what you wanna do. The idea of the block of code above, is to call a generic function each time that number is equal to a multiple of 1000.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a counter that uses a `setTimeout` to increase the value of the count, and when the count divided by 1000 is zero, call the function.

Here I've used 10 instead of 1000 to simplify the example.

```js
function fn() {
  console.log('Function called');
}

function counter() {
  function loop(count = 1) {
    console.log(count);

    // You would use count % 1000 here
    if (count % 10 === 0) fn();

    // Change the 1000 to what inverval you need
    // Here it's one second
    setTimeout(loop, 1000, ++count);
  }
  loop();
}

counter();
```